# GCP: Ansible: How to pull inventory dynamically with multiple labels when using Inventory Plugins?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, hdfs, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I'm using `ansible 2.8.4` with Google Cloud Platform. I'm using Inventory Plugins to get the dynamic inventory as ansible recommends. I've 2 hdfs clusters, so I'm pulling inventory using gcp_compute. Each cluster I have a label `index: 1` and `index: 2` so that I can pull vms dynamically based on the index.

plugin inventory(dev.gcp.yml):

```
plugin: gcp_compute
projects:
  - my-gcp-project
auth_kind: serviceaccount
keyed_groups:
  - prefix: gcp
    key: labels
compose:
  ansible_host: networkInterfaces[0].networkIP
```

Then I get dynamic groups `gcp_index_1` and `gcp_index_2` which I am using in my playbooks. Currently I have 2 playbooks one for the cluster 1 and another for cluster 2. 
In the playbooks I've hardcoded those groups like `gcp_index_1` and `gcp_index_2` which essential does the same things (except ip addresses) but deploys on different clusters.

With AWS/Azure, I used Inventory scripts, where I had my groups specified in the hosts file and then used to pull the inventory based on the multiple tags.
e.g. 
`AZURE_TAGS=stack:dev,index:1 ansible-playbook hdfs-install.yml`
In GCP, I would like to do the same but is there a way to pull inventory with multiple labels so that I can avoid duplication of having separate playbooks for each cluster.
i.e. I'd like to have one playbook and target which cluster I want to install hdfs based on multiple labels.

any suggestions how I go about acheiveing this?

Comment: I wonder is the "filters" parameter can help you. Have you checked [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/aggregatedList) already?

Comment: I would like to do this with ansible but not invoke any specfic gcloud command.If you have an example of how you do this with ansible,would be great help.

Comment: There is an example of the use of filters [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/gcp_compute.html#examples). Each additional filter in the list will act as an AND condition (filter1 and filter2). The filters available are listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list#response-body) and you can use `items[].labels` to use [Resource Labels](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources) previously specified for your instances.

Comment: By the way, there's no need to invoke any gcloud command. But the list of filter available is listed in the page for Method: instances.aggregated List that I shared first. Sorry if my comment was confusing, but I meant using filters as a parameter of gcp_compute. Can you check it and let me know if this could work? (if you still need this)

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with HDFS, but I'm assuming that the labels you refer are Resource Labels as defined in this article. Am I in the correct assumption? Or are you using Dataproc in GCP?

Comment: I'm using labels as I mentioned dev.gcp.yml file in post. I do not want to add multiple filters since that will give limit only return just hdfs ips; also this needs a change to the file if i add another hdfs cluster. Ideally I would like to implement without modifying dev.gcp.yml. In AWS/Azure, there is a dynamic inventory script which I used and that allowed me to specify multiple tags.

Comment: I was checking the documentation of the [Inventory plugin for AWS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/aws_ec2.html) that doesn't seem to be much different in options to the one for GCP. Maybe if you share your some of your setup for AWS it could be easier to understand how where you doing it. 
Also you can use [tags in your Playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html) and only run specific parts of the playbook. But I'm not sure this is part of what you need.